# modification of set raise member call on null pointer of type 'std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base' (hashtable_policy.h) error

Tags: c++

Here is my answer to a topology sort question on leetcode.
I understand this is not the best practice to modify a list on the fly.
But I got a very weird error. Here is my code.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> findMinHeightTrees(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges) {
        vector<unordered_set<int>> graph = vector<unordered_set<int>>(n, unordered_set<int>());
        vector<bool> done = vector<bool>(n, false);
        for (vector<int> & edge : edges) {
            graph[edge[0]].insert(edge[1]);
            graph[edge[1]].insert(edge[0]);
        }

        int stop = n % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
        
        while (n > stop) {
            for (int i = 0; i < done.size(); i++) {
                if (done[i]) continue;
                if (graph[i].size() <= 1) {
                    graph[*(graph[i].begin())].erase(i);
                    done[i] = true;
                    n--;
                }
            }
        }
        
        vector<int> res;
        for (int i = 0; i < done.size(); i++) {
            
            if (done[i]) continue;
            
            res.push_back(i);
        }
        

        return res;
    }
};
```

I get the following error message:

> Line 336: Char 30: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base' (hashtable_policy.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:345:30

I think this means that my return type is off.

But if I delete this line `graph[*(graph[i].begin())].erase(i);` the return type is suddenly right?

This is so peculiar, why modification of a vector affect future, yet to be declared object?

Comment: `if (graph[i].size() <= 1) { ... *(graph[i].begin()) ...}` If `graph[i].size() == 0`, dereferencing `graph[i].begin()` exhibits undefined behavior. Did you mean `>=1`?